# Using required properties on empty object

Tags: typescript

I run into this situation a lot, and I usually handle it in a way that feels wrong.  I was hoping to finally figure out how to do it properly.  I'll declare variables prior to using them, but they're guaranteed to have values, even though they're not initially set or set in the constructor.  Maybe how it's organized is actually the problem, I'm not sure, but unwrapping them feels incorrect.

```
interface Buttons {
  leftButton: HTMLElement
}

const buttons: Buttons = {}

window.addEventListener("load", load)

function load() {
  var el = document.getElementById("left-button")
  if (!el) throw new Error()
  buttons.leftButton = el

  buttons.leftButton.addEventListener("click", () => {})
}
```

I could make it optional, but then I'd have to unwrap every time I use the property.

I run into a similar situation with classes where I have to unwrap the property if I don't set it in the constructor, which feels a little better than the previous example because it's descriptive & explicitly saying "I know this wasn't set in the constructor, but it's not null"

```
class Helper {

  el!: HTMLElement

  constructor() {
    this.setElements()
  }

  private setElements() {
    this.el = document.getElementById("id")!
  }
}
```

Thanks for reading, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you just defer the creation of `buttons` until `leftButton` actually exists?

Comment: @kaya3 thanks for responding!  I didn't explain it well in the example, but in some cases it's a bigger object, and I have to break the initialization into multiple steps/functions, and even after a page loads.  I'm trying to figure out if I can "initialize" required values at a (slightly) later point than objection or class creation.  At least signal to the compiler that a value isn't ever null

Comment: You've said "unwrap" multiple times here but I'm not sure what that means; what are you unwrapping, and how?